# AJAX promise call handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ember.js, rsvp-promise

I have an Ember promise call as below;

```
var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    return $.ajax({
    //want this common
        url: requestUrl,
        type: type, // HTTP method
        dataType: dataType, // type of data expected from the API response
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(postData)
    })
    .done(function(data, status, xhrObject) {
    //But want this to be different
      // resolve call
    })
    .fail(function(xhrObject, status, error){
      // reject call
    });
})
```

My question is can I use common code for $.ajax(), but have different implementation for done() callback
I can check that by passing some parameter from the calling place.

so basically, I want

```
if (someparam == 'handleDone1')
    call resolve(data)
else
    call resolve({data})
```

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)! Just do `var promise = Ember.RSVP.Promise.resolve($.ajax(…));`.

Comment: Regarding your question - there is nothing that stops you from simply placing an `if` statement in that callback, is there?

Comment: yes, i have an external function which has the var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise() code...so if I pass any argument say 'someparam' to this external function, I cannot access that in .done(function() {..})

Comment: What do you mean by "external function"? You can access anything that you could access outside the callback also inside of it by closure.

Comment: I get an undefined for that parameter if I try passing it to done...done(function(data, status, xhrObject, paramFromExternalFn))

Comment: I never said you should declare it as a parameter? You should just use it inside.

Comment: even directly accessing it inside the done function gives undefined

Comment: Well then it probably *is* undefined. Please [edit] your question to show your full code, without a [mcve] we can't really help you.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently passing a function to `done` by hard coding a function expression into it.

Replace that with a variable. Pass a value to that variable as a function argument.

Alternatively, don't use `done` here at all. Just return the return value of `$.ajax()` and call `done()` on that in the calling function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help...but could you pls update with a rough/pseudo code so that it becomes more clear..

Answer (score 0):

return a promise instead of ajax call. And wrap the ajax call into promise.

checkout the below code. It may helps.

```
function someFunction(resolve1, reject1) {
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax({
    //want this common
        url: requestUrl,
        type: type, // HTTP method
        dataType: dataType, // type of data expected from the API response
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(postData)
    })
    .done(function(data, status, xhrObject) {
      //But want this to be different
      // resolve call
      var dicision = resolve1();
      if(dicision){
        resolve(data);
      } else {
        resolve({data});
      }
    })
    .fail(function(xhrObject, status, error){
      // reject call
    });
}
```